# Problema com o método mágico __call

Tags: php, método

Estou tentando utilizar o método mágico `__call` e a função `call_user_func_array` para recuperar o nome do método para poder carregar um arquivo. Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira

```
//Classe que importa os objetos

$obj = 'NovoObjeto';

$metodo = 'importarXML';

$objCriado = new $obj();

$objCriado->$metodo();
```

Cada objeto meu estende de uma classe chamada `FullObject` e nessa classe eu tenho a seguinte declaração do método mágico:

```
//FullObject
function __call($name,$arguments = null) {
    if(method_exists($this, $name)) { 
        $this->method = $name;
        return call_user_func_array(array($this,$name),$arguments);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('erro');
    }
}

//Classo NovoObjeto
class NovoObjeto extends FullObject {
    function importarXML() { ... }
}
```

O problema que acontece é que se não existir o método, ele lança uma `Exception`, mas se existe o método ele não passa o nome do método para a propriedade `$this->method`.

E preciso salvar este nome, pois estarei utilizando o mesmo em outro lugar, mas quero evitar ter que ser obrigado a passá-lo sempre como parâmetro.

Comment: "Estou tentando utilizar o método mágico __calle a função call_user_func_array para recuperar o nome do método para poder carregar um arquivo." - Não ficou claro o que você quer fazer, poderia explicar melhor o que deseja?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seu problema, se eu entendi corretamente, se resume a não entender como exatamente o método mágico __call() funciona e, por isso, ter criado uma lógica que jamais funcionaria como esperado.

Veja o que diz o manual (tradução livre):

> Métodos de sobrecarga são invocados quando interagindo com propriedades ou métodos que **não tenham sido declarados** ou não são visíveis no escopo atual

Consegue entender o porquê de eu ter destacado esse termo?

Se o método **não existir**, __call() será invocado. Mas o seu teste lança uma [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) caso ele não exista, logo a sua lógica mata a funcionalidade desse método de sobrecarga.

Se o método existir, __call() **não será invocado** e, com isso, sua propriedade não será populada.

O que você poderia fazer é nomear o método de alguma forma ligeiramente diferente do real, como um underline, um número ou até mesmo por simplesmente trocar a visibilidade do método (apesar de isso ser errado do ponto de vista do Princípio da Ocultação de Informação) e, então, considerar essa modificação feita no __call(), antes de invocar.

Outra possível solução, um pouco mais complexa, é usar um Design Pattern chamado [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) que, a grosso modo, é um objeto que envolve outro, alterando sua funcionalidade em *runtime*.

Comment: então, foi erro meu na digitação aqui, mas eu utilizo com os dois argumentos sim... mas não está funcionando também (já atualizei minha pergunta)

Comment: Alterar a visibilidade do método para private ou protected é válido também.

Comment: Eu entendi isso depois de ler em alguns posts a respeito.

Comment: @gmsantos: Na grande maioria das vezes é só o que basta, apesar de eu achar errado do ponto de vista do princípio da ocultação de informação. Mas como eu não tenho um espector maior do problema... Vou complementar isso na resposta também. Mais três e ganho um chapéuzinho :p

Comment: Então, também entendi o porque do OP querer usar __call ...

Comment: Pois é... Eu só uso __call() pra simular herança múltipla por pura frescura, já que além de um código eficiente eu preciso que ele seja visualmente bonito.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
$objCriado->{'_'.$metodo}();

//FullObject
public function __call($name, $arguments = null) 
{
  $realName = substr($name, 1);
  if(method_exists($this, $realName)) { 
    $this->method = $realName;
    return call_user_func_array(array($this, $realName), $arguments); 
  }else{ 
    throw new Exception('erro'); 
  } 
}
```

Descobri agora que o método mágico `__call` só é chamado quando não existe o método encontrado, daí forcei a não existir os métodos passados para que chamasse ele e pudesse fazer o que eu precisava.

Não sei se é  ou não a melhor solução, mas foi a que achei agora no momento para poder continuar.

Comment: Bom que solucionou sozinho. Eu estava terminando a resposta modificada agorinha.

Comment: "Descobri agora que o método mágico __call só é chamado quando não existe o método encontrado, "... não sei se vc tinha percebido, mas na resposta do Bruno Augusto explica isso...

Comment: Daniel Omine, percebi.. mas quando escrevi a minha resposta e baseado até mesmo no que o Bruno Augusto comentou na minha resposta. ANTES de conter isso na resposta dele, eu fiz essa postagem.  "Eu estava terminando a resposta modificada agorinha" <- se prestar atenção nesse comentário você vai entender isso... Que quando foi postada essa minha resposta ele estava fazendo a modificação da resposta dele para conter esse detalhe... Obrigado por prestar atenção nos detalhes :)